# Migration Paths

Tags: discussion, migration

Which sites do you think we need to have migration paths to, now that we are promoted?

Migration paths are an easy way to send a question to another site, without requiring it to be flagged by a moderator.

Comment: Is there documentation you can link to on Migration Paths?

Comment: Note that we do not add migrations paths because we can.  We need to see that there's a significant, demonstrated need for it and that the path would be used for good and that questions that don't belong on the destination site don't get passed.  Note that we also do not add migration paths to beta sites.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Do you have (or can you obtain) a list of sites where our questions have been migrated to?  History is the best predictor we have of the future.

Comment: @Kevin for those with the rep to have the privilege, there is a section in the [10k tools](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) that lists stats for the last 90 days.

Answer (score 12):

2012-11-16: In the [last 90 days](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats), we migrated all of 5 posts out. I really don't feel like going through all the comments on closed posts, but I'm pretty sure I've seen more comments suggesting migrations than questions that should have been migrated. So I don't think we're ready to have any migration path. Moderators can cope with one migration per fortnight or so.

---

2012-03-21 (3 months later): we've had 12 migrations in the last 90 days. So the number is on the rise (but the proportion is not: we had about 1700 questions in this time period, versus about 700 during the previous 3 months), but still very much manageable by moderators. The two targets with more than one migrated post are [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) and [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/); both of these would be risky to add as migration paths because we don't want questions to be migrated out just because they are about a movie or about a book. Moderators will remain the sole migrators for the forseeable future; if you think a post should be migrated, flag it.

Comment: +1 for actually getting the data.

Comment: Ditto DKV's comment :)

Answer (score 3):

I think Literature, Movies, Physics, Gaming, and possible English, would be the best sites. Many questions coming here don't quite fit, and I think they would tend to be sent to one of these sites.

Comment: Also perhaps gaming? For instance someone might ask a completely game-related question, where the game is set in the Star Wars Universe.

Comment: I added Gaming as it's definitely a high-overlap subject matter.

Comment: Is there any evidence that these (theoretically good) paths actually were used in the last 90 days?

Comment: literature and movies are both in beta, and it seems reasonable to guess that they are months away from launching (given that they are both new to beta).  (physics looks like the beta style for me - bad caching or did they not get a design?).

Comment: What about Skeptics?

Comment: @TonyMeyer We got a polished look that was darker than meta.scifi and there was a user rebellion. It was, IMHO, a nice look, but tough on the eyes to swap to/from the rest of the intertubes. Eventually the rebels won and they switched us back to the beta look until Jin gets [a round tuit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round_tuit). Could be a while.

Comment: @Tom: Jin has shown us our *new* graduated design. Yeah!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) and [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/) will turn out to be good migration paths.

Comment: Both are in beta, so you cant do a migration path.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Hence the "will turn out to be".

Comment: Are there any stats on how many we've actually migrated to either?

Comment: I don't have any, but I should have made clear that I wasn't suggesting adding them _now_ but rather to keep an eye on them.

Comment: There's been only one, thus I'd say it's not an issue at all.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I think there've been a few others in the past that were migrated to Physics that would fit on Astronomy

Comment: Physics has had a few, but not many. Only m&tv has a large number.

Comment: @phantom42 http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats

Comment: @Keen We also just got [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68636/what-is-the-most-massive-planet-a-human-could-stand-on) and [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68714/are-there-formulae-for-non-ftl-starship-speeds-and-and-relative-time-passed), and who knows how many more that get closed without being migrated

Comment: I think I meant @PearsonArtPhoto for that.  Oh well, both pinged

Answer (score -1):

## We should definitely have a migration path to Literature.

[story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) is really big here, and we somewhat regularly get questions on it about non-speculative fiction books or short stories. Some of the time these are actually quite good, such as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/215214/102999), but I have to do a mod flag. It'd be easier if we could just vote to migrate without bothering with that, but we don't have a migration path there (or to **anywhere**, for that matter).

Comment: In the last 90 days, two questions have been successfully migrated to Lit. Frankly, the level of *needed* migrations is so low that it's better and easier for it to just be managed by the mods through the use of a custom flag *"I think this should be migrated to x"*

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure that the literature mods would necessarily want us having a migration path that allows us to more easily dump our crap onto their site