# Can we add other SE sites to the "it doesn't belong here" flag submenu?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migration Paths](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/migration-paths)

Sometimes I flag a question that doesn't belong here and the only StackExchange site option is meta.scifi. Can we add the the Literature and Movies & TV SE sites to this menu? I think it would lessen the burden on the moderators and help to migrate questions that do not fit here but fit somewhere else just fine.

Comment: ADoes anyone know what happens if a Q is closed and the closers indicate that it belongs on another site? Does it just add a message to the close reason, or does it flag it for moderator attention somehow?  I could see the latter being useful....

Comment: @beofett tell the poster to flag it for the mods and put that as the custom message.

Comment: @Kevin My original comment (which I subsequently deleted) was that I didn't see the benefit of additional migration paths. I'm not sure that users with enough rep to VTC should be flagging for migration, unless closing as off-topic with a migration path doesn't do anything aside from closing. Looking at [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123117/166646) it seems that the migration paths allow non-moderators to migrate (unless I'm reading this wrong). I don't think this is a feature we're anywhere close to needing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. At least not until we start migrating a lot more questions. See Rebecca Chernoff's comment [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/migration-paths#comment2121_1030)