# Do we want a straight migration path to Anime&Manga?

Tags: feature-request, scope, migration, anime

If and when [Anime&Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) comes out of beta, do we want to add a straightforward migration path there? I can imagine some overlap, and I can imagine some questions asked *here* that would receive a quicker answer *there*.

Example of such a question: *["Transformers Victory toyline - was there a God Ginrai toy?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49434/19561)*
It's a question about a toy, made after an anime. I'd say it's better suited there than here.

I understand we generally want a site to come out of beta before adding a path. Do we want to wait in this case as well?

Comment: Technically, it doesn't need to come out of beta. There was some relevant discussion [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3077/5184) about how migration paths work and such.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that it was a _technical_ (or rather, techincally _imposed_) limitation.

Comment: @ATS Going over my comments to you earlier in chat, that *does* seem to be what I was implying, but not what I meant. Sorry about that, should've been clearer. :)

Comment: @ATS Are you an Anime & Manga.SE user?  Have you read their listing of what is and is not on topic there?

Comment: @Keen: good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a need for this.  Since September there have been 2 migrations involving us and Anime & Manga.SE.  And both of them were migrated to us.  So no, I don't think we need a migration path to Anime & Manga.SE because it's so rare we mods can handle them.

See also:
[Migration Paths](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/migration-paths#comment2121_1030)

Comment: And practically nothing has changed since then. ..